# Jquery datetimepicker - Advance time by 1 hour

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm currently using the jQuery datetimepicker add-on from [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

It works just about perfectly, but I'm stumped on how to add a small bit of functionality to it. I currently have two instances on a page, one for start-time and one for end-time. When I choose a start-time, I'd like to automatically fill in the end-time with the start time + 1 hour.

Can this be accomplished without extending the core script at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will add one hour to the end-time datepicker.

```
$('#dtStartDate').datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
       var startDate = $('#dtStartDate').datetimepicker('getDate'));
       var endDate = new Date(parseFloat(startDate.setHours(startDate.getHours()+1)))

       //Get the ending date datepart
       var endDateDatePart = endDate.getFullYear() + '/' + endDate.getMonth() + '/' + endDate.getDate();

       //calculate the ending date time part including AM/PM
       var endDateTimePart;
       if (endDate.getHours() > 12) { endDateTimePart = endDate.getHours()-12 + ':' + endDate.getMinutes() + ' PM';} else {endDateTimePart = endDate.getHours() + ':' + endDate.getMinutes() + ' AM';}
       $('#dtEndDate').datetimepicker('setDate', endDateDatePart + ' ' + endDateTimePart );
   }
});
```

Comment: OK, I think I have it very close, but I'm getting peculiar results in the start time field, as sometimes the time will not enter into the field. Could you take a look?
`
// Increment the end time by one hour when the start time is selected.
 $(".end").datetimepicker({ampm: true,stepMinute: 10});
 $('.start').datetimepicker({
  ampm: true,stepMinute: 10,        
  onSelect: function(){
     var start = $('.start').datetimepicker('getDate');
     var end = new Date(parseFloat(start.setHours(start.getHours()+1)));
     $('.end').datetimepicker('setDate', end );
    }
 });`

Comment: @jwburnside: if you remove the onSelect event of the start datepicker, does start time field get populated every time?

Comment: Yes, the start time field works as intended if I just use the original code<br />
$(".start").datetimepicker({ampm: true,stepMinute: 10});<br />
$(".end").datetimepicker({ampm: true,stepMinute: 10});<br />

Maybe I am not initializing the datetimepicker instances correctly when I try to use your code?

Comment: Try changing  var startDate = $('#dtStartDate').datetimepicker('getDate'));  to  var startDate = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate'));

Comment: No, still has the same bug. It seems to work the first time I select a day and then a time, but it is disabled afterwards. Weird. *Update* Looks like it is the last line that is the culprit:
$('.end').datetimepicker('setDate', end );

Comment: Try remove one line at a time (starting at the last line) from the onSelect and test.  Hopefully we can find on which line the failing occurs.

Comment: It's the last line definitely, $('.end').datetimepicker('setDate', end );

Comment: It could be simply a matter of the endDate not being formatted properly for the datepicker.  What date format are you using?

Comment: I'm using the format: 05/27/2011 02:00 pm, which I should be the default since I haven't made any specific changes to the date.

Comment: Actually, it might be the date. It comes out as:Sat May 14 2011 00:50:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time). I'll see if I can format it real quick

Comment: This must be it.  You can do something like: var endDateConverted = endDate.getFullYear()
    + '/' + endDate.getMonth()
    + '/' + endDate.getDate()
    + ' ' + endDate.getHours()
    + ':' + endDate.getMinutes();

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with new code that will provide the date and time in your format with AM/PM specified.

Comment: Alright, I got it. For reasons unknown it the datetimepicker setDate would disable the startDate field, so I just used a myform.time_end.value = endDate to correct it. I also added a time formatting script so I didn't have to mess with the conversion, which you can find here:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format
Thanks for the help!

Comment: there is an extra parenthe at the end of line 3

Answer (score 2):

yes, it extends the JQuery-UI Datepicker which has different callbacks to handle a selection

you can check out the [onSelect documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) and use it on your timepicker

```
$('#example').datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
              //add 1 hour to start time
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Get and Set Datetime function shown near the bottom of the page.

```
var ex13 = $('#example13');

ex13.datetimepicker();

$('#example13_setdt').click(function(){
    ex13.datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()) );
});

$('#example13_getdt').click(function(){
    alert(ex13.datetimepicker('getDate'));
});
```

Could you use that? Or course you'll have to add an hour to the getDate.

```
$("#endtime").datetimepicker("setDate", $("#starttime").datetimepicker("getDate"));
```