# validate date using datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery.datetimepicker.js to provide a Calendar to user to pick date and time. I want to validate this date because user might manually modify the date in the text field.

How to validate it?

Please help. Following is the code where I set the calendar to the text field.

```
 <script   src="<c:url value="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.js" />" ></script>

  <script>
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   j( document ).ready(function() { 

   j('#dateId').datetimepicker({
     format: 'm/d/Y  g:i A'       
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate the date time in datepicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838720/how-to-validate-the-date-time-in-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Placing `readonly="readonly"` inside the input tag, so you don't need to validate it.

Update:
1. If validateOnBlur is true(default value is true) and the user input invalid format, the datetimepicker will handle it and set the today as input value;
2. If the date is invalid, for example, 2014/07/32, the datetimepiker handle it and set 2014/08/01 as the current date, but the input textbox is still 2014/07/32. You can add the OnChangeDateTime function to handle it.
like:

```
    $("#input").datetimepiker({
        format: "Y/m/d",
        OnChangeDateTime: function (currentDate, $input) {
            $input.val(currentDate.getFullYear()+"/"+(currentDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+currentDate.getDay());
        }
    });
```

You need to add the 0 before month/day if they are less than 10.

You can also analyze $input.val() and give user an alert if input is invalid.

Comment: BUt my situation is user might have to enter time manually sometimes